# js form filling checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

How could i return user to unfilled field when he push "submit" button?

I have something like this:

```
    <!--Contact Name-->
    <div class="section" id="inputdiv">
         <span class="fieldname">Name:</span>
         <input type="text" id="contactname" /> <!-- Nessesary to be filled-->
           <script type="text/javascript">
               var contactname = new LiveValidation('contactname');
               contactname.add(Validate.Presence);
           </script>  
    </div>


     <a class="button-more" style="width:903px; float: right; font-size: 15px; margin-top: 15px;" href="">Submit my answers</a>
```

Or just this:

```
<input type="text" id="contactname" /> <!-- Nessesary to be filled-->

<a href="">Submit my answers</a>
```

Comment: Provide an id to your link like 'sbmit' , then add the following line jQuery('#sbmit').click(function(e){ if(jQuery('#contactname').val()=="") e.preventDefault();});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form validation shouldn't happen only in the front with HTML and JS since it's too easy to bypass. You should also do some checks in your backend.

That being said, you'll need to actually have a form in order to check correctly its validity. For instance:

```
<form id="abcd">
 <input id="input" />
</form>
```

then

```
$("abcd").submit(function(e){
  return ( $("#input").val() != "" );
});
```

I used jQuery syntax, but it's basically the same thing with normal JS.

If you could also use all the nice plugins out there like http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

If you don't want a form, just do a test on click on the submit link and test the value here.

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the following code while the user clicks "Submit":

```
if (document.getElementById('contactname').value=='') document.getElementById('contactname').focus();
else // if the field isn't empty, proceed
```

**EDIT:** Oh, I'm sorry, I've just noticed the "jquery" tag. Does it have to be created in jQuery? I don't know jQuery, but you may use the above code as well ;)

And remember, you should also check all the fields on the server's side as some experienced user may easily manipulate the client-side code.

Comment: JS os ok, I'm noob it it. Could you show how should I apply it on "Submit" button?

Comment: You can put my code into a function, for example CheckContactName(). Then, add the onclick event to your button. For example: `<a href="#" onclick="CheckContactName()">Submit my answers</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you want to allow people who are not running javascript in their browsers to use your form, you should be using a `<input type="submit" />` button followed by server-side validation, with javascript validation as a shortcut for those users who are running it.

To add javascript validation, you can either attach some javascript to the form's submit event, or to the click event of an anchor:

```
    <form name="example" action="example.asp" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return validate(this) ;">
        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Button-Label" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate(frm) {
            var message = '' ;
            if(frm.contactname.length < 1) {
                // Put cursor in field.
                if(message.length < 1) frm.contactname.focus() ;
                message = message + 'Please enter your name.\n' ;
            }
            if(message.length > 0) {
                alert(message) ;
                // Stop the form submitting
                return false ;
            }
            return true ;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: action="example.php" I use .asp actually) Could you show how will work an added "submit button"?

Comment: Since all the processing is tied to the form's onsubmit event, it doesn't matter how the form is submitted. I have added a submit button to the example, but it would just as easily work if the submit was fired by javascript attached to an anchor: `<a onclick="javascript:document.getElementByID('exampleform').submit() ;">Submit Form</a>`